# pytype raise error with attrs default factory decorator

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, python-attrs, pytype

`mypy` give no error, but `pytype` can't handle this code and rise `attribute-error`. How can I fix it?

Code:

```py
# foo/__init__.py
from typing import List

import attr


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class A:
    x: List[int] = attr.ib()

    @x.default
    def bar(self) -> List[int]:
        return [1]
```

Log:

```
pytype foo
Computing dependencies
Analyzing 1 sources with 0 local dependencies
ninja: Entering directory `/home/iaro/sample/.pytype'
[1/1] check foo.__init__
FAILED: /home/iaro/sample/.pytype/pyi/foo/__init__.pyi 
/home/iaro/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/tmp-eIhQjmCm-py3.7/bin/python -m pytype.single --imports_info /home/iaro/sample/.pytype/imports/foo.__init__.imports --module-name foo.__init__ -V 3.7 -o /home/iaro/sample/.pytype/pyi/foo/__init__.pyi --analyze-annotated --nofail --quick /home/iaro/sample/foo/__init__.py
File "/home/iaro/sample/foo/__init__.py", line 11, in A: No attribute 'default' on List[int] [attribute-error]

For more details, see https://google.github.io/pytype/errors.html#attribute-error.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Versions:

```
attr.__version__
'19.3.0'
mypy --version
mypy 0.770
pytype --version
2020.04.22
```

P.S. I want to do it without `# pytype: disable=attribute-error` in `@x.default` line

Comment: Have you checked if that’s a known problem with pytype? Lools like they don’t support the decorator syntax?

Comment: @hynek yes, I open issue https://github.com/google/pytype/issues/573, they don't support `@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)`, decorators works only with  classic  `@attr.s` syntax